# Do you know how to set the code to running Dark Mode systems only in the my App without the Light Mode?

Tags: swift, colors, ios13, ios-darkmode

I am looking for the simple of the code to accessing whole of my apps into the dark mode only.

For example:

I know the iOS 13/14 has automatically Light Mode and Dark Mode in the systems-wide. Now The developer can enable only light or dark for while of the app's systems with the iOS Dark Mode features. Like Apollo, Twitter, and more that Customize can enable the dark mode, But the point that I want to look for Enable only Dark Mode with Blur, Color, and more that has two options for system-wide that I want to enable only Dark Mode with the code to running it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dark/light mode for every view controller, add this code in your view controller

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark 

        //for example 
        if self.overrideUserInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            print ("dark")
        }
  }
```

Comment: This is so great answer! What's about add the code in the AppDelegates.Swift? I believe the App Delegates is a part of more set the automatically for rest of the app.

Comment: in sceneDelegate.swift  add in func scene this  window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark

Comment: There have five func in that folder which can I put in the func?

Comment: Use First func  Scene